# Which part of this bash PS1 config determine the color?

Tags: bash, colors, prompt

I got my git branch color set by this tutorial:http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/624

But recenlty I've reverted my terminal background color, and the yellow branch name is nearly invisible under grey background. So I need to change this config:

```
export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[01;33m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[01;34m\] \$\[\033[00m\] '
```

The problem is, I can't discern which part determines the color in the above code.

Comment: See the Arch Wiki page on [color bash prompts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#List_of_colors_for_prompt_and_Bash)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a color definition:

Foreground

```
\[\033[1;30m\]
```

Background

```
\[\033[44;1;31m\]
```

Cheers,

Comment: Is this RGB? what rules does this follow?

Comment: Nope, the colors come from the following list:

    `Black       0;30     Dark Gray     1;30
    Blue        0;34     Light Blue    1;34
    Green       0;32     Light Green   1;32
    Cyan        0;36     Light Cyan    1;36
    Red         0;31     Light Red     1;31
    Purple      0;35     Light Purple  1;35
    Brown       0;33     Yellow        1;33
    Light Gray  0;37     White         1;37`

Comment: Wonderful, I love this world

Comment: Isn't `44;1;31m` setting both foreground *and* background?

Answer (score 4):

Those colors are determined by [terminal control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). For a near-complete reference have a look at the [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), most terminal emulators nowadays are mostly compatible to XTerm.